# set moveSlides 2 on Bxslider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have made bxslider and set it up the slides moves 2 columns when click control buttons. 
The problem is when slides elements(LI) are total 5 or odd, last slide moves only 1 column.

How to make it move 2 columns always

This is my code here

```
<div class="mainDiv">

<ul class="masterSlider">

    <li data-slide="1">1 </li>
    <li data-slide="2">2</li>
    <li data-slide="3">3 </li>
    <li data-slide="4">4</li>
    <li data-slide="5">5</li>

            </ul>

</div>


var masterSlider;
$(document).ready(function(){
    masterSlider = $('.masterSlider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        captions: false,
        pager: false,
        minSlides:2,
        maxSlides: 2,
        moveSlides:2,
        slideWidth: 100,
        slideMargin: 10
    });
    $('.masterSlider').on('click', 'li', gotoSlide);
});
function gotoSlide() {
    var idx = (parseInt($(this).data('slide')) + masterSlider.getSlideCount() - 2) % masterSlider.getSlideCount();
    masterSlider.goToSlide(idx);
}


.masterSlider li {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#999;
}
ul{list-style-type:none;}
.mainDiv{width:700px;border:solid 2px red;}
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/4ktkmfdL/53/

Comment: bxSlider creates clones of the first and last slide if it is in infinite loop.mode. Moreover, an extra clone is created should the you ever have an odd number slides.